# imageView.setImageResource(int resId) vs. imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);

Tags: android, bitmap

The image file is identical. Once it comes from the `drawable` and one from the `file system`.

Here is the code.

```
         <ImageView
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:id="@+id/partner_logo"
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/parter_logo"
                />
```

I would like to set the partner logo dynamically, so I load id from the webserver and then

set with `imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);`

with the ImageResource it looks good and as I expect but in `Bitmap` case it is too small.

Here the picture to compare

---

The Logo (black arrow points) was set via `setBitmap`. It seem not to be up-scaled

[image]

--

The Logo (read arrow points) was set via `setImageResource`. It looks as I would like it too look like.

[image]

So the question is why there is a difference here? Works the `scaleType` in case of bitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setImageResource()` automatically scale your image.

If you want to use `setImageBitmap()` you need to scale up your bitmap to your desired size or using `setAdjustViewBounds(true)` that keep your aspect ratio.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourbitmap, width, height, false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks, this has worked, but I wonder if the `android:scaleType` does not work for the `Bitmaps`?

Comment: @herrlado You can not use both `setAdjustViewBounds(true)` and `scaleType`.